# Identifying price swings/trends in pandas dataframe with stock quotes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with DatetimeIndex and ohlcv stock quotes columns. I would like to extract price swings/trends that meet a certain threshold: up swings/trends/moves bigger than 0.3$ and down swings/trends/moves that go beyond -0.3$.

```
df[:10]
                           close   high   low    open    volume
2014-05-09 09:30:00-04:00 187.5600 187.73 187.54 187.700 1922600
2014-05-09 09:31:00-04:00 187.4900 187.56 187.42 187.550 534400
2014-05-09 09:32:00-04:00 187.4200 187.51 187.35 187.490 224800
2014-05-09 09:33:00-04:00 187.5500 187.58 187.39 187.400 303700
2014-05-09 09:34:00-04:00 187.6700 187.67 187.53 187.560 438200
2014-05-09 09:35:00-04:00 187.6000 187.71 187.56 187.680 296400
2014-05-09 09:36:00-04:00 187.4100 187.67 187.38 187.600 329900
2014-05-09 09:37:00-04:00 187.3100 187.44 187.28 187.400 404000
2014-05-09 09:38:00-04:00 187.2600 187.37 187.26 187.300 912800
2014-05-09 09:39:00-04:00 187.2200 187.28 187.12 187.250 607700
```

After studying pandas documentation it looked like the Dataframe.apply() would be the approach, but I got stuck in building the function(s). As my coding abilities are limited overall I need a little help please.

```
global row_nr
row_nr = 1
def extract_swings()
    if row_nr == 1 : pivot = row.open ; row_nr += 1
    else : if (row.high-pivot) >= 0.3 : ????
    ... ????

df['swings'] = df.apply(extract_swings, axis=1)
```

The result should be this:

```
df['swings'][:10]
2014-05-09 09:30:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:31:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:32:00-04:00 -0.35
2014-05-09 09:33:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:34:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:35:00-04:00 0.36
2014-05-09 09:36:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:37:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:38:00-04:00 NaN
2014-05-09 09:39:00-04:00 -0.59
```

UPDATE: To avoid any confusion here is how the requested function should go through the dataframe:

```
                           close    high   low    open    volume 
2014-05-09 09:30:00-04:00 187.5600 187.73 187.54 187.700 1922600
# this is the first line, first minute and we well take row.open 187.70 as \
# the starting point or first pivot
2014-05-09 09:31:00-04:00 187.4900 187.56 187.42 187.550 534400
# next minute we check if either (row.high - pivot) >= 0.3 or \
# (row.low-pivot) <= -0.3. Neither is true so nothing to do here.
2014-05-09 09:32:00-04:00 187.4200 187.51 187.35 187.490 224800
# next minute same check ... we see that row.low-pivot = -0.35. \
# We consider 187.35 a second pivot and the diff value -0.35 a first trend down
2014-05-09 09:33:00-04:00 187.5500 187.58 187.39 187.400 303700
# next minute we check if the identified trend/swing down goes further \
# down by having a row.low lower than previous row.low. If we would \
# have found here a new lower row.low that would be the second pivot \
# and we would forget about 187.35 as being a pivot ... and so on. \
# We don't see that on this row, instead we see prices are higher than \
# previous row, so we start checking the diff for a potential up trend \
# starting from second pivot 187.35. As long as we do not encounter a \
# higher high with over 0.3 above last pivot we are still within the identified down trend. 
2014-05-09 09:34:00-04:00 187.6700 187.67 187.53 187.560 438200
# we don't see a lower low to reconsider the second pivot neither \
# a (row.high- second_pivot) >= 0.3
2014-05-09 09:35:00-04:00 187.6000 187.71 187.56 187.680 296400
# here we see (row.high- second_pivot) = 0.36. We consider 187.71 as \
# a third_pivot and the diff value 0.36 as an up trend (from second pivot to here)
2014-05-09 09:36:00-04:00 187.4100 187.67 187.38 187.600 329900
# next minute we check if the identified trend/swing up goes further up \
# by having a row.high higher than third pivot. If we would have found here \
# a new higher row.high that would be the third pivot and we would forget \
# about 187.71 as being a pivot ... and so on. We don't see that on this row,\
# instead we see prices are lower than previous row, so we start \
# checking the diff for a potential down trend starting from third \
# pivot 187.71. As long as we do not encounter a lower low with \
# over 0.3 below last pivot we are still within the identified up trend.
2014-05-09 09:37:00-04:00 187.3100 187.44 187.28 187.400 404000
# we find here a (row.low - third_pivot) = 0.43 so we have identified \
# a new down trend starting from third pivot and now we have a potential\
# fourth pivot 187.28 
2014-05-09 09:38:00-04:00 187.2600 187.37 187.26 187.300 912800
# we find here a lower low so we don't consider 187.28 the fourth \
# pivot anymore but this lower low 187.26
2014-05-09 09:39:00-04:00 187.2200 187.28 187.12 187.250 607700
# we find here a lower low so we don't consider 187.26 the fourth pivot anymore \
# but this lower low 187.12. Being this the lowest low we consider this one \
# to be the fourth pivot and the diff 187.12-187.71=-0.59 as a downtrend with that value
```

Comment: I need a solution very similar to this zigzag library here: [link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jbn/ZigZag/blob/master/zigzag_demo.ipynb)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit tricky since you cannot mark a point as pivot until you find the next potential pivot (ie if you are in an upward trend, you can't say it's done until you find a low sufficiently low).

This code does the trick - I've put your data in the tmpData.txt file for convenience, and get the desired result. Please check

```
def get_pivots():
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('tmpData.txt')
    data['swings'] = np.nan

    pivot = data.irow(0).open
    last_pivot_id = 0
    up_down = 0

    diff = .3

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        row = data.irow(i)

        # We don't have a trend yet
        if up_down == 0:
            if row.low < pivot - diff:
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = row.low - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.low, i
                up_down = -1
            elif row.high > pivot + diff:
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = row.high - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.high, i
                up_down = 1

        # Current trend is up
        elif up_down == 1:
            # If got higher than last pivot, update the swing
            if row.high > pivot:
                # Remove the last pivot, as it wasn't a real one
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] + (row.high - data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'high'])
                data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] = np.nan
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.high, i
            elif row.low < pivot - diff:
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = row.low - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.low, i
                # Change the trend indicator
                up_down = -1

        # Current trend is down
        elif up_down == -1:
             # If got lower than last pivot, update the swing
            if row.low < pivot:
                # Remove the last pivot, as it wasn't a real one
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] + (row.low - data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'low'])
                data.ix[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] = np.nan
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.low, i
            elif row.high > pivot - diff:
                data.ix[i, 'swings'] = row.high - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row.high, i
                # Change the trend indicator
                up_down = 1

    print data
```

Output:

```
date                  close  high    low     open    volume    swings                                            
2014-05-09 13:30:00  187.56  187.73  187.54  187.70  1922600     NaN
2014-05-09 13:31:00  187.49  187.56  187.42  187.55   534400     NaN
2014-05-09 13:32:00  187.42  187.51  187.35  187.49   224800   -0.35
2014-05-09 13:33:00  187.55  187.58  187.39  187.40   303700     NaN
2014-05-09 13:34:00  187.67  187.67  187.53  187.56   438200     NaN
2014-05-09 13:35:00  187.60  187.71  187.56  187.68   296400    0.36
2014-05-09 13:36:00  187.41  187.67  187.38  187.60   329900     NaN
2014-05-09 13:37:00  187.31  187.44  187.28  187.40   404000     NaN
2014-05-09 13:38:00  187.26  187.37  187.26  187.30   912800     NaN
2014-05-09 13:39:00  187.22  187.28  187.12  187.25   607700   -0.59
```

Comment: Yes @Pawel-Kozela ...thank you for your effort. It seems to get the desired result on a first check ... but looping in plain python through over 1 mil lines takes too long. I would prefer a vectorized solution if possible ...

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure it can be done with apply() operations as we need the history of the stock for current row evaluation. What kind of speedup factor would work for you ? I've checked on my solution, using iterrows() cuts the execution time by 4, but it would still be around 1m30 secs for 1.5 mil lines.

Comment: It looks like Pawel's solution is the only one to work ... after all. I made a few minor adjustments: 1.replaced "irow(0)" with "iloc[0]" as it will be deprecated; 2. used iterrows() and made it a little faster (1.5 mil lines in 2m51s vs +5min); 3. replaced "row.low < pivot - diff" with "((pivot-row.low)/diff)>1" and "row.high > pivot + diff" with "((row.high-pivot)/diff)>1" because I was getting some swings below the threshold ... can't explain why !?

Comment: I still find it slow, since I'm used to work with pandas in seconds or tens of seconds not minutes, but, until someone else suggests a better one I'll make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the code of tw0000 as he had a little bug on the lines with 'O' instead of cols[0]

```
def get_pivots(df, cols=['O','H','L', 'C']):

  df['swings'] = np.nan
  df.loc[df.index[0], 'swings'] = df.loc[df.index[0], cols[0]]
  df.loc[df.index[-1], 'swings'] = df.loc[df.index[-1], cols[0]]

  pivot = df.loc[df.index[0], cols[0]]
  df.loc[df.index[0], ]
  last_pivot_id = 0
  up_down = 0

  diff = .3

  for i, row in df.iterrows():

      # We don't have a trend yet
      if up_down == 0:
          if row[cols[2]] < pivot - diff:
              df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[2]] - pivot
              pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[2]], i
              up_down = -1
          elif row[cols[1]] > pivot + diff:
              df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[1]] - pivot
              pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[1]], i
              up_down = 1

      # Current trend is up
      elif up_down == 1:
          # If got higher than last pivot, update the swing
          if row[cols[1]] > pivot:
              # Remove the last pivot, as it wasn't a real one
              df.loc[i, 'swings'] = df.loc[i, 'swings']
              df.loc[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] = np.nan
              pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[1]], i
          elif row[cols[2]] < pivot - diff:
              df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[2]] - pivot
              pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[2]], i
              # Change the trend indicator
              up_down = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

how about, assuming you only care about highs for the moment:

```
startPx = df.open.iloc[0]
level = ((df.high - startPx) / .3).astype(int)
df['swings'] = level - level.shift(1)
```

now, to find out what the differences are, you would just do something like:

```
changes = df[df.swings != 0]
diffs = changes.high - changes.open.shift(1)
```

Comment: Not a solution. Please see my per row explanations above.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about it this morning and realized it wouldn't work, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

so i haven't tested this, but something like this will get you what you want. what happens if both the `low < pivot - diff` and `high > pivot + diff` in the same minute?

```
def f(df):
    pivot = df.open.iloc[0]
    diff = .3
    def proc(ser):
        res = np.nan
        if ser.low < pivot - diff:
            res, pivot = ser.low - pivot, ser.low
        elif ser.high > pivot + diff:
            res, pivot = ser.high - pivot, ser.high
        return res

    df['swings'] = df.apply(proc, axis=1)
```

Comment: Would not work ... because the trick is, as @Pawel-Kozela already identified, that you cannot mark a point as pivot until you find the next potential pivot (ie if you are in an upward trend, you can't say it's done until you find a low lower by 0.3). His solution works but it's very slow because it's pure python looping (~5min for 1.5 mil lines)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer from @Pawel-Kozela to be compatible with the latest version of pandas, and added an easy way to pass column names.

```
def get_pivots(df, cols=['O','H','L', 'C']):

    df['swings'] = np.nan
    df.loc[df.index[0], 'swings'] = df.loc[df.index[0], cols[0]]
    df.loc[df.index[-1], 'swings'] = df.loc[df.index[-1], cols[0]]

    pivot = df.loc[df.index[0], cols[0]]
    df.loc[df.index[0], ]
    last_pivot_id = 0
    up_down = 0

    diff = .3

    for i, row in df.iterrows():

        # We don't have a trend yet
        if up_down == 0:
            if row[cols[2]] < pivot - diff:
                df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[2]] - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[2]], i
                up_down = -1
            elif row[cols[1]] > pivot + diff:
                df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[1]] - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[1]], i
                up_down = 1

        # Current trend is up
        elif up_down == 1:
            # If got higher than last pivot, update the swing
            if row[cols[1]] > pivot:
                # Remove the last pivot, as it wasn't a real one
                df.loc[i, 'swings'] = df.loc[i, 'swings']
                df.loc[last_pivot_id, 'swings'] = np.nan
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[1]], i
            elif row[cols[2]] < pivot - diff:
                df.loc[i, 'swings'] = row[cols[2]] - pivot
                pivot, last_pivot_id = row[cols[2]], i
                # Change the trend indicator
                up_down = -1
```