# Find price pattern correlations on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4YZN.png) given a financial dataset I have created a dataframe from it. I would find the correlation from price drops and price bounces (the ratio of bounce/drop persentage) please see pseudo code:

```
        for i, row in df['Close']:
               if i in row A > i in row B and 
                  i in row B > i in row C
                  new_df['Drop']   = A.pct_change(B) 
                  new_df['Bounce'] = B.pct_change(C)
                  new_df['Ratio']  = new_df['Drop'] / new_df['Bounce']
```

So: from a dataframe of financial data I would like to find the following pattern: If the price drops measure the % of the drop then when it goes up again measure the % of this and divide the persentages of the drop and bounce in order to get the ratio of the movement.

I have found code that kinda helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614259/identifying-price-swings-trends-in-pandas-dataframe-with-stock-quotes)
Greatly appreciated any help!

Comment: For us to help you we need more information about your dataset structure and exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK, you've computed the drop-to-bounce ratio.  Now, what do you want to correlate that against?

Comment: I just want to compute the drop to bounce ratio in order to examine the statistics of this analogy and build a custom DCA bot like the 3commas.io DCA bot works